# Google Spreadsheet - How to write the correct If statement and Browser.msgBox return function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am try to figure out is, how to write the if statement, so that it will send a separate email based on the two values it will check in the spreadsheet.

Here are the two values that are in Column N:

**"In Progress"**

**"Completed"**

Here is the code section:

```
var sheetNameToWatch = "Active Discs"; // Active spreadsheet that contains the data
var columnNumberToWatch = 14; // Column N
var valueToWatch1 = "In Progress"; // First value to watch for in column N
var valueToWatch2 = "Completed"; // Second value to watch for in column N
/*var valueToWatch3 = "Rejected"; // Third value to watch for in columns for labeled PM         Review and Date Discs Shipped*/
var timestamp = new Date(); // Timestamp
var activeSessionuser = Session.getEffectiveUser(); //Get the current user in the     spreadsheet
var replyTo = 'test@test.com';

function sendEmailNotifications(e) {
//Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    try{
var ss = e.source;
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = e.range;

//Checks the variables sheetNameToWatch + columnNumberToWatch + valueToWatch1 ("in progress")
//Sends Email to Venue Colombo Team
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.columnStart == columnNumberToWatch && (e.value == valueToWatch1)){

    var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Email will be sent to the Venue Colombo Team. Do you want to sent this email?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO); 
if(confirm.toLowerCase()=='yes'){sendColomboMessage(e.range.rowStart)};
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Email Sent to Venue Colombo Team')
}
```

This section I am stuck trying to write the "else" or "else if" statement that will watch for value "Completed and send a different email.

```
 else (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.columnStart == columnNumberToWatch && (e.value == valueToWatch2)){

    var confirm = Browser.msgBox('Email will be sent to the Venue Colombo Team. Do you want to sent this email?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO); 
if(confirm.toLowerCase()=='yes'){sendVCSMessage(e.range.rowStart)};
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Email Sent to VCS Team')*/

}catch(err){Logger.log('catch err = '+err)}
}
```

Lastly, when I add "return;" to the code for the Browser.msgbox, it does not stops the code from running or the entire function stops working. Where or how do I add the return; if the user click "No". Then it should close the message box and do nothing.

```
if(confirm.toLowerCase()=='yes'){sendColomboMessage(e.range.rowStart)};
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Email Sent to Venue Colombo Team')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are after (there is a lot of repeated functionality that could be broken out into another function):

```
var sheetNameToWatch = "Active Discs"; // Active spreadsheet that contains the data
var columnNumberToWatch = 14; // Column N
var valueToWatch1 = "In Progress"; // First value to watch for in column N
var valueToWatch2 = "Completed"; // Second value to watch for in column N
/*var valueToWatch3 = "Rejected"; // Third value to watch for in columns for labeled PM         Review and Date Discs Shipped*/
var timestamp = new Date(); // Timestamp
var activeSessionuser = Session.getEffectiveUser(); //Get the current user in the     spreadsheet
var replyTo = 'venueclientservices@rrd.com';

function sendEmailNotifications(e) {

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  Logger.log('sendEmailNotifications()');

  try {

    var ss = e.source;
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.range;
    var ass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var confirm;
    var getName = sheet.getName();
    var columnStart = range.columnStart;

    Logger.log("getName: " + sheet.getName());
    Logger.log("columnStart: " + range.columnStart);
    Logger.log("e.value: " + e.value);

    if (getName == sheetNameToWatch && 
        columnStart == columnNumberToWatch) {

      if (e.value == valueToWatch1) {

        Logger.log("Value 1");

        confirm = Browser.msgBox('Email will be sent to the Venue Colombo Team. Do you want to sent this email?', 
                                 Browser.Buttons.YES_NO); 

        if (confirm.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {

          sendColomboMessage(e.range.rowStart) 

          ass.toast('Email Sent to Venue Colombo Team')

        } else {

          ass.toast('Edit In Progress but no email sent');

        }

      } else if (e.value == valueToWatch2) {

        Logger.log("Value 2");

        confirm = Browser.msgBox('Email will be sent to the VCS Team. Do you want to sent this email?', 
                                 Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);

        if (confirm.toLowerCase() == 'yes') { 

          sendVCSMessage(e.range.rowStart);
          ass.toast('Email Sent to VCS Team');

        } else {

          ass.toast('Edit Value 2 but no email sent'); 

        }

      } else {

        ass.toast('Edit, but no email sent.');

      }

    } // matching sheet and col

  } // try

  catch (err) {

    Logger.log('catch err = ' + err);

  }

  function sendColomboMessage(row) {

    Logger.log("sendColomboMessage, row: " + row);
  };

  function sendVCSMessage(row) {

    Logger.log("sendVCSMessage, row: " + row);
  };

} // sendEmailNotifications()
```

Comment: Life Saver!! Thank Andrew Roberts, you solved my problem and exceeded what I needed. Can't thank you enough!!